# How to get an object without doctrine in an action?

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I have an `editAction($id)` in my controller which have to display my edit form to edit a company.

So I have to get the current object to display these information in my form.

With doctrine I do this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$user = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Company')->find($id);
...
```

and in my `edit.html.twig` I can use my object `$user` as I want (ex: `$user->getName`)

But here I do not use Doctrine because my data are coming from an api and the actions (add, delete and edit) concerns the api directly, that is to say when I update a company the changes concerns the api and not a database.

I have an entity `Company` which is not mapped with doctrine because I do not need it.

So how can I do to get my current Company object in my action to passed it to my form then ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use or write your own parameter converter, which is provided by the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle. This will map a request parameter (for example the ID) to for example an object.

Have a look at the dedicated chapter in the documentation, which also explains [how to write your own converter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter).